# How can I edit PyQt Header height without editing the width?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

When I run this code, the header is much taller than I want it to be - how can I edit the height without changing the width?  (I don't want to edit the width as it is variable)

```
headers = ['A','BCDE','FG','HIJKLMN','OP','QRST','UVWX','Y','Z']
length = len(headers)

for i in range(length):  
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()  
    item.setText(headers[i])  
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)  
    font = QtGui.QFont('Cambria Math', 10, QtGui.QFont.Light)  
    item.setFont(font)  
    self.tableWidget2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "much taller"? The height is mostly determined by the font size - why can't you just set a smaller size?

Comment: The font size is 10 - as seen above, but the height of the header is at least 3-4 times the height of the font.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour on Linux, but presumably you are on Windows. What happens if you don't set a font? And have you tested with different fonts?

Comment: Other fonts work as expected, but I need one that has the XOR symbol (cross in a circle) and that was the only one that I could find.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!! Found a font that supports it but doesn't make it higher.